# What does "What we in Georgia call: All day long" mean?

Tags: dialogue, flight

In the movie *Flight* (2012) there is a scene in which the owner of the airline is talking about Denzel Washington's character (the pilot). 
A lawyer states that the pilot could spend the rest of his life in prison if convicted and the airline owner responds:

> Life in prison, or what we in Georgia call: "All day long".

[Here is a clip](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/e01a028f-e4cb-463e-9d56-81fa38bc1560)

I know Georgia was (maybe still is, haven't checked) a state with death penalty, so initially I thought he meant the pilot wouldn't stay long in jail, because he would end up executed. However that doesn't make sense, since the punishment for his crime would be up to life in prison, and not death sentence.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a metaphor.  All day long = your whole life

Comment: I can understand why this was downvoted and ended up in the "Low quality" queue - one-line answers are generally frowned upon - but I'm not sure what else needs to be said here. Perhaps a reference indicating that this is indeed a saying in Georgia?

Comment: @F1Krazy ... I don't think its being downvoted just because it's a short answer.  I believe its because it missed the point of the line.  I could be incorrect, but I don't think this is a saying in Georgia. The "what we call in " construction is often used for mild jokes.

Answer (score 0):

The [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Flight.pdf) makes it abundantly clear that "all day long" is slang for "life imprisonment"

> **MR. CARR:** *He’s going to jail.  He belongs in jail.  You bet your ass he’s going to jail, the question is...is he gonna die in jail?*
>
> **HUGH LANG:** *You’re wrong, Mr. Carr.*
>
> **CARR’S ATTORNEY:** *Last time I checked, 6 counts of manslaughter is life in prison.*
>
> **MR. CARR:** ***Life in prison, what we in Georgia call “all day long.”***
>
> [It goes quiet as everyone reflects on that reality.]

The absence of the word "or" shows that this isn't an either/or proposition.